# Unable to fix a bug on Opera mini browser ( Android )

Tags: android, debugging, browser, opera-mini

I have a small HTML game which works fine on all browsers including mobile browsers.
The only problem is with Opera Mini browser on Android devices.

I can debug my game on Chrome using ADB chrome plug-in. But is there any way to find out what's wrong on Opera mini?

Comment: As far as I know, Opera Mini uses some-kind of precaching, which sorta defeats online gaming sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you : [Remotely debugging Opera for Android](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/remotely-debugging-opera-for-android/)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (about Opera for Android only) do not cover Opera Mini specifically.

For Javascript debugging, there is an Opera article/blog [Opera Mini and JavaScript](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/) published in Sept 2012, describing the process in details using MicroEmulator.

Essentially you can have a `server:console` report with `console.log()` also supported.

PS: I doubt an HTML/JS game is going to work in Opera Mini though. 
Having a web site work on Opera Mini and look decent is hard enough. ^^

What's wrong with Opera Mini in this case is that it processes Javascript on the server side.